# I do not understand why it is necessary to protect a single-instruction setter with a mutex

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, race-condition, thread-synchronization

I have a source code that does something like this:

```
void setX(int x) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(m_lock);
  m_x = x;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(m_lock);
}
```

This method is executed by several threads concurrently.

I have read that it is necessary to protect it with mutex to make it thread-safe, **but I do not understand why is this necessary.**

As far as I understand, since the method executes **only one instruction, it will be always atomic** (thread-safe) regardless you use a mutex or not.

So, my question is: **is there any way through which the above method, without mutexes, can generate a race condition?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on context. In probably **most** languages/systems, assigning an **int** value to a field is an *atomic* operation.

But theoretically, that isn't guaranteed. If you had a system only able to deal with 8 bit bytes assigning a 2 or 4 byte int value would not be atomic!

And as soon as you change the type of the variable/field from int to say long, all bets are off anyway. In that sense, the above code is simply overly "conservative". But it has one advantage: in case you ever decide to change the type of that field/parameter to something that can't be assigned atomically - no further changes are required.

Thus: you are correct - using a mutex isn't required here. But it doesn't hurt either (maybe except things as allowing for dead locks or performance impacts due to adding the need to acquire a lock).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the mutex may be to insure that the assignment is visible to other threads.  I don't know whether that's C or C++ code in your example, and I don't know what vintage of C or C++.

In earlier versions of C and C++, the language's *memory model* is implementation defined behavior, but in later versions, the language spec dictates a memory model which, I believe is somewhat like the memory model of a Java program.

In Java, If thread A assigns a value to an ordinary `int` variable without using any kind of locking, and then thread B subsequently examines the variable, also without locking, then thread B could see either the value that was assigned by thread A, or it could see the previous value.  There's no guarantee of when (or even *if*) thread B will ever be able to see the new value.

The situation changes if the threads use a mutex.  In that case, the rule is that whatever thread A wrote to the variable before unlocking a mutex will become visible to thread B after thread B locks the same mutex.